# Finding most efficient sorting algorithm

Tags: sorting, efficiency

Arr is an array that contains $ n$ numbers.
Suggest the most efficient algorithm for each case and analyze the runtime.
Explain why the algorithm you chose is the best one.

1. Arr contains exactly $\frac{n}{5}$ distinct values.
2. Arr contains integers in the range $[0, … , ^7 − 1]$.
3. There are exactly ( − √) integers in Arr, which are between 1 to 100. The remaining √ elements are not integers.

I was trying to look at some of the sorting algorithms and try to figure one by one which one is the best, but I believe there's a better way to do it.
What would be the right approach?

Comment: Your approach sounds fine. Changes are that you have only seen a handful of sorting algorithms, so it'll be really quick to evaluate all of their complexities for cases 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @Steven However, it's possible to improve by combining algorithms. For instance, for the third case it might be interesting to do a counting sort for the integer values, a heapsort for the remaining and then a merge. If I'm not mistaken, this should yield a O(n) sort.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. You are perfectly right. I did not pay enough attention to the statement. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) Use any $O(n \log n)$-time sorting algorithm, like Mergesort. Without additional assumptions on the elements you cannot do better.

For 2) Use Radix sort with any base $b = n^\epsilon$ for any constant $\epsilon \in (0, 1]$ of your choice. For example pick $\epsilon =1$ so that $b=n$. The time needed for each iteration of Radix sort will be $O(n+b) = O(n)$. The number of iterations will be $O(\log_b n^7) = O(7 \log_n n) = O(1)$. The overall time is then $O(n)$.

For 3) As Jean-Claude Arbaut points out: find the integer elements and sort them once for all with counting sort. This requires time $O(n)$. Sort the remaining $\sqrt{n}$ element with any $O(n^2)$-time sorting algorithm. For example Mergesort or insertion sort. This takes time $O\left(\left( \sqrt{n} \right)^2\right) = O(n)$. Finally, merge the two sorted arrays in time $O(n)$ (similarly to the Merge step of Mergesort). The overall time required is $O(n)$.